# External is unresolved for some reason

Tags: c++, linker, external

I have a simple offsets.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

struct offsets_s {
    uintptr_t dwGlowObjectManager;
    uintptr_t m_iGlowIndex;
    uintptr_t dwEntityList;
    uintptr_t dwLocalPlayer;
    uintptr_t m_bDormant;
    uintptr_t m_iTeamNum;
} offsets;

offsets_s getOffsets() {
    return offsets;
}

void setOffsets() {
    offsets.dwGlowObjectManager = 0x528B880;
    offsets.m_iGlowIndex = 0xA428;
    offsets.dwEntityList = 0x4D43AB4;
    offsets.dwLocalPlayer = 0xD2FB84;
    offsets.m_bDormant = 0xED;
    offsets.m_iTeamNum = 0xF4;
}
```

And an offsets.h file for it:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

struct offsets_s {
    uintptr_t dwGlowObjectManager;
    uintptr_t m_iGlowIndex;
    uintptr_t dwEntityList;
    uintptr_t dwLocalPlayer;
    uintptr_t m_bDormant;
    uintptr_t m_iTeamNum;
};

offsets_s getOffsets();

void setOffsets();
```

Here's the start of my Source.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Offsets.h"

DWORD fMain(HMODULE hMod)
{
    uintptr_t client = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(TEXT("client_panorama.dll"));

    offsets_s offsets = getOffsets();
    setOffsets();
```

When I try to compile it, it says that getOffsets() and setOffsets() are unresolved externals:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "struct offsets_s __cdecl getOffsets(void)" (?getOffsets@@YA?AUoffsets_s@@XZ) referenced in function "unsigned long __cdecl fMain(struct HINSTANCE__ *)" (?fMain@@YAKPAUHINSTANCE__@@@Z) - Source.obj line 1

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl setOffsets(void)" (?setOffsets@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "unsigned long __cdecl fMain(struct HINSTANCE__ *)" (?fMain@@YAKPAUHINSTANCE__@@@Z)  - Source.obj line 1
```

What should I do to make the code work?

I think offsets.cpp compiled in, atleast according to this:
[image: solution explorer]

Comment: Are you compiling `offsets.cpp`?

Comment: Looks like `offsets.cpp` is not part of your Visual Studio project. Putting it in the same folder as `Source.cpp` is not  enough.

Comment: How do I check that? @drescherjm

Comment: Look in Solution Explorer

Comment: It is in the solution explorer source files

Comment: OT: you have `#pragma once` and `struct offsets_s { ... };` in your `offsets.cpp` which don't belong there. Instead you should include `offsets.h`

Comment: thanks, removed them, and I included Offsets.h

Comment: @drescherjm It was because Visual Studio didnt compile it for some reason even though it should have been compiled. I bet the guy who closed this didnt even look at the question

Comment: Most questions like this will get closed for that reason. That is the catch all for these types of problems. The duplicate will talk about your source file not being in the project however it will not discuss unusual situations like yours.

Comment: Do you know how in the future I could make sure that source files are compiled?